# Как добавить НТТР заголовки при отправке запроса через file_get_contents?

Tags: python, php, request

Есть сайт https://www.rusprofile.ru/, я делаю на него GET запрос и получаю информацию.
Так это выглядит на Python(за код не бейте создан просто для тестов):

```
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 YaBrowser/23.7.2.765 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer L1kxBFdKWw7SqVfHv_7hO_MDDdvt0mHB'
}

r = requests.get(f'https://www.rusprofile.ru/ajax.php?query=231005683170&action=search&cacheKey=0.7611668130906286', headers=headers)
print(r.json())
```

Так все отлично работает, если убрать какой-то из заголовков даст ошибку 403. Так вот при почти аналогичном коде на php  передачи в запрос заголовков всё-равно дает ошибку 403, php я почти не знаю, может что не так делаю подскажите пожалуйста.
Код PHP:

```
<?php
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 YaBrowser/23.7.2.765 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36"."Authorization: Bearer L1kxBFdKWw7SqVfHv_7hO_MDDdvt0mHB"
  )
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts_1);

$r = file_get_contents("https://www.rusprofile.ru/ajax.php?query=231005683170&action=search&cacheKey=0.7611668130906286", false, $context);
echo $r
?>
```

Comment: `"."` это конкатенация строк. И значит токен ты не передаешь. Перенос строки это `\r\n`. `'header'=>"User-Agent:...\r\nAuthorization:...."`

Comment: Спасибо ваш вариант сработал)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас хедер в варианте с php передаётся одной сторокой.

Попробуйте записать вот так:

```
'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=> [
      "User-Agent" => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows N/...",
      "Authorization" => "Bearer L1kxBFdKWw7S.....MDDdvt0mHB"
     ]
  )
```

И убедитесь, что у вас токен реальный не совпадает с тем что вы тут выложили

Меня ещё смущает способ делать запрос к сайту через file_get_contents, но пусть это будет на вашей совести.

Comment: Спасибо ваш вариант действительно сработал)
Но если не ошибаюсь массивы в php это array() тогда почему здесь используется []?

Comment: `[]` это сокращенный синтаксис для `array()`

Comment: Я хотел спросить почему тогда не работает array(), а [] работает, но сервер опять начал возвращать ошибку 403, код не менялся, не подскажите что может быть, на python  все по прежнему работает. И на чтобы вы посоветовали заменить file_get_contents?

Comment: В отправке запросов через file_get_contents нет абсолютно ничего предосудительного. Простой и удобный способ. Надо всего лишь прочитать документацию

Comment: ну да, вместо того чтобы сделать запрос одной строкой через `file_get_contents` давайте напишем 10 через curl или вообще добавим к проекту из одного файла композер и поставим guzzle. Чтобы не смущало, а то везде ведь через курл все пишут.

Comment: @teran ну, по-хорошему, там [не одна строчка](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52662522/). Чтобы ту же 403 отдебажить, надо добавить параметр ignore_errors, парсить $http_response_header, вот это вот всё. Но опять же, я не говорю, что курл лучше. Я к тому, что для продакшена это скорее две равнозначные библиотеки, каждая из которых не лучше и не хуже другой. Хотя чтобы разово дернуть гет запрос, file_get_contents конечно удобнее

Comment: @Ипатьев я про варианты, когда чисто по ссылке получить контент. Тут то явно адепт писать все через курл, как мне показалось по крайней мере.

Comment: Подскажите еще пожалуйста, делаю запрос на этот сайт https://xn--b1aew.xn--p1ai/wanted и через file_get_contents такая ошибка Warning: file_get_contents(): SSL: Success in /home/runner/Php/main.php on line 85

Warning: file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto in /home/runner/Php/main.php on line 85

Warning: file_get_contents(https://xn--b1aew.xn--p1ai/wanted): failed to open stream: operation failed in /home/runner/Php/main.php on line 85, а через curl такая мOpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to xn--b1aew.xn--p1ai:443